# PHP if else question regarding simple to do list

Tags: php, mysql

To do list:
I have created the HTML and php code to insert data into the database, and read from it.
Database is looking like this:

```
task_id |task_desc |task_target |task_finished_date |task_status
40      |test p    |2020-07-25  |2020-07-23         |completed
```

Task_target and task_finished_date are using type date in the database.
task_target is getting value on creation of the task, and task_finished_date is getting automatically value when we mark the job completed using now():

```
$task_id = $_GET['completed'];
    mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE tasks SET task_status = 'completed' WHERE task_id=". $task_id);
    mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE tasks SET task_finished_date = now() WHERE task_id=". $task_id);
    mysqli_query($db, "ORDER BY task_finished_date DESC ". $task_id);

    header("Location: index.php" );
}
```

I am currently trying to program it when some task is completed AFTER the deadline to be displayed in "Failed" table, and if is closed before the deadline to be displayed in completed table.

```
    <tbody>
        <?php $i = 1; while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($finished_tasks)) { ?>
            <tr>
                 <?php 
                      if($targetd > $finished_d){ ?>
                       
                       <td class="successful"> <?php echo $i; ?> </td>
                       <td class="successful"> <?php echo $row['task_desc']; ?> </td>
                       <td class="successful"> <?php echo $row['task_finished_date']; ?> </td> 
                  <?php  }?>
            </tr>
        <?php $i++; } ?>    
    </tbody>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>N</th>
            <th>Failed Tasks</th>
            <th style="width: 197px;">Task finished time</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <?php $i = 1; while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($finished_tasks)) { ?>
            <tr>
                 <?php 
                      if($targetd < $finished_d){ ?>
                       
                       <td class="failed"> <?php echo $i; ?> </td>
                       <td class="failed"> <?php echo $row['task_desc']; ?> </td>
                       <td class="failed"> <?php echo $row['task_finished_date']; ?> </td> 
                  <?php  }?>
            </tr>
        <?php $i++; } ?>    
    </tbody>
```

As in the $finished_tasks variable i have storing the values for the completed tasks:

```
$finished_tasks = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE task_status = 'completed' ");
$finished_task_time = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT task_finished_date FROM tasks WHERE task_status = 'completed' ");
$planned_target_time = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT task_target FROM tasks WHERE task_status = 'completed' ");         
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($finished_tasks)) {
                       $targetd = $row['task_target'];
                       $finished_d = $row['task_finished_date'];
```

Have tried to get the deadline(task_target)and target(task_finished_date) and insert them in both variables and then compare them, and based on this comparison to display them where I want, but the logic here is not right I think.

How I can separate the tasks based on the desired condition?

Entire Code Below:

```
<?php 
    // initialize errors variable
    $errors = "";

    // connect to database
    $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "todo");

    // insert a quote if submit button is clicked
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        if (empty($_POST['task_desc'])) {
            $errors = "You must fill in the task";
        }else{
            $task_desc = $_POST['task_desc'];
            $task_target = $_POST['task_target'];
            $sql = "INSERT INTO tasks (task_desc, task_target) VALUES ('$task_desc', '$task_target')";
            mysqli_query($db, $sql);
            header('location: index.php');
        }
    }   
// delete task
    if (isset($_GET['del_task'])) {
        $task_id = $_GET['del_task'];

        mysqli_query($db, "DELETE FROM tasks WHERE task_id=".$task_id);
        header('location: index.php');
    }
if(isset($_GET['completed'])){
    
$task_id = $_GET['completed'];
    mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE tasks SET task_status = 'completed' WHERE task_id=". $task_id);
    mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE tasks SET task_finished_date = now() WHERE task_id=". $task_id);
    mysqli_query($db, "ORDER BY task_finished_date DESC ". $task_id);

    header("Location: index.php" );
}

    // select all tasks if page is visited or refreshed
    $tasks = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE task_status = 'Active' ");

?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

    <title>ToDo List Application PHP and MySQL</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Page Content -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <!-- Blog Entries Column -->
              <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="heading">
        <h2 style="font-style: 'Hervetica';">ToDo List Application PHP and MySQL database</h2>
    </div>
    <form method="post" action="index.php" class="input_form">
        <?php if (isset($errors)) { ?>
            <p><?php echo $errors; ?></p>
            <?php } ?>

        <label for="task_target">Select Date:</label>
        <input type="date" class="form-control" name="task_target">
        <label for="task_desc">Describe your task:</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" name="task_desc" id="body" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea>
        <button type="submit" name="submit" id="add_btn" class="form-control">Add Task</button>
    </form>
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>N</th>
                <th>Ongoing Tasks</th>
                <th>Target Date</th>
                <th>Action</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <?php $i = 1; while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($tasks)) { ?>
                <tr>
                    <td> <?php echo $i; ?> </td>
                    <td> <?php echo $row['task_desc']; ?> </td>
                    <td> <?php echo $row['task_target']; ?> </td> 
                    <td> 
                        <a href="index.php?del_task=<?php echo $row['task_id'] ?>">Delete</a> 
                    </td>
                    <td> 
                        <a href="index.php?completed=<?php echo $row['task_id'] ?>">Complete</a> 
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php $i++; } ?>    
        </tbody>
    </table>    
<?php   
    
    $finished_tasks = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE task_status = 'completed' ");
    $finished_task_time = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT task_finished_date FROM tasks WHERE task_status = 'completed' ");
    $planned_target_time = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT task_target FROM tasks WHERE task_status = 'completed' ");         
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($finished_tasks)) {
                           $targetd = $row['task_target'];
                           $finished_d = $row['task_finished_date'];   

?>  
    
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>N</th>
                <th>Successful Tasks</th>
                <th style="width: 197px;">Task finished time</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <?php $i = 1; while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($finished_tasks)) { ?>
                <tr>
                     <?php 
                          if($targetd > $finished_d){ ?>
                           
                           <td class="successful"> <?php echo $i; ?> </td>
                           <td class="successful"> <?php echo $row['task_desc']; ?> </td>
                           <td class="successful"> <?php echo $row['task_finished_date']; ?> </td> 
                      <?php  }?>
                </tr>
            <?php $i++; } ?>    
        </tbody>
        
    </table>
        <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>N</th>
                <th>Failed Tasks</th>
                <th style="width: 197px;">Task finished time</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <?php $i = 1; while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($finished_tasks)) { ?>
                <tr>
                     <?php 
                          if($targetd > $finished_d){ ?>
                           
                           <td class="failed"> <?php echo $i; ?> </td>
                           <td class="failed"> <?php echo $row['task_desc']; ?> </td>
                           <td class="failed"> <?php echo $row['task_finished_date']; ?> </td> 
                      <?php  }?>
                </tr>
            <?php $i++; } ?>    
        </tbody>
        
    </table>          
            
                    
           <?php } ?>
            </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, this will not be uploaded to public. Only for learning purposes.

Comment: First of all, try not to mix PHP and HTML. Prepare the data before displaying HTML.

Comment: It doesn't matter who is it for. You have a bug which you need to fix as soon as possible.

Comment: "Thanks, this will not be uploaded to public. Only for learning purposes. – Kristiyan Rumenov " Then it is advised to learn the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite ambiguous, what kind of error or unexpected output are you getting?

Comment: Hi Samuel, It seems that the logic is not working as it is in my head. I have no errors but just not working as expected. In my mind it have to be something like: Reading each row of the database and compare both dates, after that based on the comparison marking each row as completed successfully or failed.

Comment: I myself am having a hard time trying to get the logical flow of the code and this is because of the unhealthy PHP and HTML mixtures. Makes the code quite difficult to read and understand. Let me try one more time.

Answer (score 0):

Had to strip your code of the HTML part and the PHP part not affecting the logic, here's what I have.

```
    $finished_tasks = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE task_status = 'completed' ");
$finished_task_time = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT task_finished_date FROM tasks WHERE task_status = 'completed' ");
$planned_target_time = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT task_target FROM tasks WHERE task_status = 'completed' ");         
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($finished_tasks)) {
                       $targetd = $row['task_target'];
                       $finished_d = $row['task_finished_date'];   



   
$i = 1; 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($finished_tasks)) 
{

    if($targetd > $finished_d)
    { 

    echo $i;  
    echo $row['task_desc'];  
    echo $row['task_finished_date'];  


    $i++; 
    }    


    $i = 1; 
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($finished_tasks)) 
    { 
    if($targetd > $finished_d)
    { 

    echo $i; 
    echo $row['task_desc']; 
    echo $row['task_finished_date']; 
    }

    $i++; 
    }     



}
```

1. All three while loops assign a value to the $row variable. This would cause some unexpected results as some values may be skipped.
2. You're referencing the SQL result indexes inappropriately.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to find a easy fix of my question.
First of all thanks to all who tried to help me and advised way of effective learning.
Really like this place.
So, on the answer:
As in the begging i have described that the Deadline of the task is defining during the creation of the task, and the closing time is getting to the database when the user click Completed button.
So i have decided to have the sort directly into the database modifying the queries like this:

```
    $finished_tasks = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE task_status = 'completed' AND task_finished_date < task_target ");
    $finished_failed_tasks = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE task_status = 'completed' AND task_finished_date > task_target ");
```

In this way i have all of the completed successfully tasks in $finished_tasks variable and all of the failed in $finished_failed_tasks, after that the displaying in the page is easy.
I am not quite sure if this is practical solution, but in this way working as i desired.
Next step is to strip and refactor the code as you suggested.
Once again, thanks really much and have a nice day.
Regards, Kristiyan